# react-redux animation lag when state changes

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm using react-redux in a react native app.
i have an icon toggle which animates a ripple when you toggle it.
(from here: https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit#toggles, you can see it in the gif)

basically my state looks something like this:

```
{
    isChecked : false
}
```

and the component is something like this:

```
<MKIconToggle checked={checked}
              onCheckedChange={change => changeState(change.checked)}>
    <Image source='img1'/>
    <Image state_checked={true} source='img2'/>
</MKIconToggle>;
```

then i have a reducer to act on CHANGE_STATE actions and return a new state with true or false accordingly from the payload.

the thing is it lags horribly, i think because its re-rendering while the animation is still running.
(i checked, when i do nothing in the reducer and just return the current state it runs smoothly)

how would you suggest solving this? the only thing i can think about is dispatching an async action with a timeout to delay the action. but that just feels wrong.

Comment: also delay wont work because i have a few of these buttons and then if you toggle them one after the other the render cycles interfere with each other and i get the lag anyway.

Comment: What about extracting the redux state into some local state variable and working with the local variable in your component, but still updating your global state as well?

Comment: how will that be different? if i'm updating the global state it will still trigger a render.

seems to me that there might be something inherently wrong with the way i'm doing this.
this problem would apply to any animation that is still going on while state changes (which triggers a render) in the same connected component.

Comment: I have the same issue in my app, have you figured out how to solve the state change/refresh squashing your animation problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your state change with `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions`

```
    <MKIconToggle checked={checked}
      onCheckedChange={change => {
         InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(()=>changeState(change.checked))}}>
    <Image source='img1'/>
    <Image state_checked={true} source='img2'/>
</MKIconToggle>;
```